# Poisson process in a disaster relief station

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, queueing-theory, birth-death-process

$\textbf{Q}: $Suppose you are helping out in a disaster relief, at a relief station. Assume that every morning, supplies will be delivered to the station, and that the amount of supplies delivered is a Poisson distributed r.v. with parameter $\lambda$. Furthermore, each supply (here we consider each supply as a single object) in the morning is drawn and distributed to affected populations from the relief station with probability $p$, before the replenishing of supplies the next morning.

Note that the storage capacity of the station is finite, of value $N$, and that should there be a case where the sum of the amount of supplies delivered every morning and that of the number of present supplies in the station exceeds $N$, the amount of supplies in the station will be capped at $N$.

So given the above information, formulate a stochastic model that describes the amount of supplies in the station every morning, just before the resupply that same morning.

$\textbf{Edit/ Addition:}$  I will like to formulate parameters for the model, that allows me to compute the mean number of stock that can be found in the station's storage, and also the expected amount of supplies being drawn from the station, which is not destroyed due to lack of storage.

$\textbf{My thoughts:}$ My approach is to view this as a question on birth and death processes, but part of me strongly tells me to approach this question as a queueing model. With regards to the birth and death process approach, I came up with the birth and death parameters to be $\lambda$ and $pN$ respectively. Is my approach and conceptual understanding wrong? Some clarification will be deeply appreciated as I am still new to $\textit{birth and death processes}$ as well as $\textit{queueing theory}$, having just studied topics on Poisson processes.

Comment: I would guess that it's not a birth and death process, since according to the Wikipedia article you can only increase or reduce stock by one. Could you be more specific about what you are supposed to do? Do you have something to compute, rather than "formulate a model"?

Comment: A model would be: $X_n = \min (X_{n-1} + Y_{n-1}, N) - Z_{n}$ with $X_n$ amount of stock at the morning $n$. $Y_{n-1}$ sequence of independent Poisson r.v.s and $Z_{n} \sim Bin(m, p)$  a binomial with $m = \min(X_{n-1} + Y_{n-1}, N).$

Comment: @Kore-N I think you misunderstood my question when you stated "increase or reduce stock by one". In fact, the amount of stock delivered can vary, which is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda$. Also, the amount of stock drawn (decreased) may not be one, as the probability of a stock being drawn is $p$. As for your question, I will like to formulate parameters for the model, that allows me to compute the mean number of stock that can be found in the station's storage, and also the expected amount of supplies being drawn from the station, which is not destroyed due to lack of storage.

Comment: I will add the above in for clarification on the formulation of the stochastic model.

Comment: I meant that in the "definition" of birth/death process you can only increase/reduce stock by 1. For this reason it does not seem to fit your model. But of course you can define your own birth/death process.

Comment: @Kore-N Ah I apologize for misinterpreting that.. Then if that's the case, are there any kinds of stochastic processes that fits my question's criteria? For e.g. Renewal theory, queueing theory (in particular the M/M/1system), etc